# using HtmlAgilityPack how to load encoded html string

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

I am working on converting html string to pdf. I am currently using ExpertPDF to do this process.

But int he process i have to clean the Html string and then pass the cleaned html string to the library which will create the pdf.

in cleaning process the first step is to remove the unwanted html tags (some thing like removing tags which are from blacklist. the list will be created by me.). to remove the unwanted tags i am using the HtmlAgilityPack to parse the html string and remove the nodes

second step is to Auto close the knows tags if they are opened .when i load the html string using HtmlAgilityPack it auto closes the tags which is good. but i have come across a problem here. the issue is when there is some text like "reading < 5 then go and visit doctor". the less than symbol treats it as the start of the tag and then close it some where down the line.

for example : the below is the html

```
> <p style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; line-height: 16.9px;
> background-color: #ffffff;">1. The full evaluation and management of
> acute coronary syndrome, ST-elevation and non-ST-elevation myocardial
> infarction is beyond the scope of SOC tele-intensivist coverage. 2.
> Early cardiology consultation should be recommended in all cases of
> suspected acute coronary syndrome or myocardial infarction 3. However,
> one of these syndromes is suspected, it is reasonable to recommend
> starting therapy with ASA, beta-blockers, nitrates, and morphine
> sulfate. 4. In addition, full dose anticoagulation with
> anticoagulation (e.g. unfractionated heparin, enoxaparin, or
> fondaparinux), second antiplatelet agent (e.g. clopidegrol) and
> initiation of statin therapy (atorvastatin 80 mg orally daily) should
> be considered 5. For patients with heart failure or ejection fraction
> < 40%, ACE-inhibitors (or ARB’s if history of ACE-inhibitors
> intolerance) should be considered. 6. Other more routine options are
> listed below.</p>
```

after using HtmlAgilityPack and load the above html and htmldocument node will have an outterxml as below

```
> <p style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; line-height: 16.9px;
> background-color: #ffffff;">1. The full evaluation and management of
> acute coronary syndrome, ST-elevation and non-ST-elevation myocardial
> infarction is beyond the scope of SOC tele-intensivist coverage. 2.
> Early cardiology consultation should be recommended in all cases of
> suspected acute coronary syndrome or myocardial infarction 3. However,
> one of these syndromes is suspected, it is reasonable to recommend
> starting therapy with ASA, beta-blockers, nitrates, and morphine
> sulfate. 4. In addition, full dose anticoagulation with
> anticoagulation (e.g. unfractionated heparin, enoxaparin, or
> fondaparinux), second antiplatelet agent (e.g. clopidegrol) and
> initiation of statin therapy (atorvastatin 80 mg orally daily) should
> be considered 5. For patients with heart failure or ejection fraction
> < 40%,="" ace-inhibitors="" (or="" arb’s="" if="" history="" of=""
> ace-inhibitors="" intolerance)="" should="" be="" considered.="" 6.=""
> other="" more="" routine="" options="" are="" listed=""></p>
```

treating < 40%  as a tag and it closes at the end and marking inbetween text as attributes.

can you please tell me what i have to do in order to load the string into html document and don't treat < as the starting tag. Is there a way for me to load the document as encoded text instead od plain string text ?

Thanks,
Raj.

Comment: Please show some code to duplicate the issue. It may be that you found a bug in HTMLAgilityPack, or that it's being extra strict about parsing the `<` character. Ideally you'd fix your input so that you don't have unescaped `<` characters within text.

Comment: You should try other parsers as well, like `AngleSharp`, perhaps you will not face such problem.